# SSD Disk size for Windows 7 ultimate with bit locker

Tags: windows-7, ssd, bitlocker

I’m planning to switch to Windows 7 Ultimate with bit locker and I would like to speed up my workstation (notebook) with buying SSD disk. I found out most affordable are for me 120 GB ones, what I’m not quite sure about if is it enough for SP1 and Bit locker (never used)?

Answer (score 1):

BitLocker requires a separate system partition, which is 100MB.  Other than that, your disk space requirement will be dependent on what programs do you plan to run.

Comment: Can I install this parttion after installing system?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  It is a pain in the rear though.  I remember seeing a few obscure guides on technet about doing this during the WIn7 RC beta.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 with a 80 GB SSD disk. It is very very very fast. The Windows directory is 17.7 GB large. After installing my most important programs I have 40 GB free. That I thing you should have no problem with 120 GB. Else you need very large data like videos.

Comment: I was working on workstation PC where I had 100 Gb partition with Windows 7 Professional. And After some time and many updated installed I have to move my outlook file and many programs to other partition. So that’s why I’m bit concerned about 120Gb when switching to Ultimate version.

Comment: Interesting. Have you check the size of Windows, programs files and users folder. Which folder has consume the hard disk?